# form data utf-8 encoding failed at posting data on server in android

Tags: android, utf-8, android-volley, utf8mb4

I am sending a fill-up form with some input fields like name, mobile, photo, status.

And status could fill-up with **emoji** also.

So I tried this with doing to send this whole data in form-data and header set to utf-8.

But when I send data to server, server recived it with **?????????????????**.

But when i check this with postman, server received perfectly.

my **code snippets** are.

```
public static void makeMultiPartPostRequest(Activity activity, final VolleyRequestHandler handler, final int requestType, String url, final Map<String, String> params, final boolean showDialog, final boolean withTag, String tag, byte[] byteArr, String type) {
        PhotoMultiPartRequest postRequest = new PhotoMultiPartRequest(url, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (showDialog)
                    Common.dismissProgressDialog();
                handler.onErrorResponse(error, requestType);
            }
        }, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {
                if (showDialog)
                    Common.dismissProgressDialog();

                handler.onResponse(response.toString(), requestType);
            }
        }, byteArr, params,type);
```

//

```
 params.put(AppConstants.DESCRIPTION, "" + descriptionText.getText().toString());
```

//

```
mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        mBuilder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

**please excuse typos**

Comment: We cannot see what you put in `params`. Nor how you use them. Use predefined stings in your post please. Post a more complete example.

Comment: params.put(AppConstants.DESCRIPTION, "" + descriptionText.getText().toString());

Comment: You don't have to repeat your code. I of course already saw that. Reread my comment. I asked something different.

Comment: I am sorry. I think I am not getting your need? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Emoji require `utf8mb4` in MySQL.  MySQL's `utf8` stops at 3-byte codes, which excludes Emoji.

You will need

- 4-byte Emoji characters in the client.
- `SET NAMES utf8mb4` (or equivalent) at the time of connecting to mysql.
- `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` on the table/column

Comment: Check the 3 bullet items I added.